Не передаются данные на другой сайт через curl_
Мне нужно передать методом POST массив с данными на другой сайт. Коннект с сайтом есть, т.е. я могу вернуть какой-нибудь ответ, чтобы убедится, что всё ок, но вот $_POST приходит пустым. В чем может быть проблема?
public function httpPost($data)
    {
        $url = 'http://crm.acrohappiness.ru/api';
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        
        $html = curl_exec($ch);
        
        curl_close($ch);    
        
        echo $html;
    }


как вы узнали что $_POST приходит пустым?

@Ипатьев так через var_dump вернул результат

я проверил вашу функцию на https://httpbin.org/post, данные передаются. смотрите у себя, что вы там передаете и что принимаете

@Ипатьев да и в файл json должен записываться результат, а он пустой становится

@Ипатьев передаю обычный массив с БД. Принимаю так:
file_put_contents('regions.json', json_encode($_POST));

Я не просил это мне рассказывать. Я сказал смотреть у себя. Вы из обычной формы пробовали отправить запрос, без курла? Вы курлом проверили отправку на httpbin.org/post?
